# Importing data from text file and sorting it

Tags: vba, excel, import, excel-2007

I'm working on a lot of pcb projects and we have an excel file that we have to enter a lot of values by hand (A drill table actually). I've some issues now...

1. Macro Not Saving

When I create the macro that imports the text, I can save it but when I open the excel file again the macro is gone.

Here is the code that I'm using to import a file:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportTextFile()
Dim fName As String

fName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files, *.tap; *.drl")
If fName = "False" Then Exit Sub

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & fName, _
        Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
            .Name = "sample"
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 437
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierNone
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "" & Chr(10) & ""
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
               1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
               1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
               1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

2. Sorting Values

Once I have my report imported, it looks like this:

```
;HEADER: 271-138-131-011 
;CODE  : ASCII 
;FILE  : ncdrill-1-10.drl for  ... layers TOP and BOTTOM
;DESIGN: 131-011.brd
;T01 Holesize 1. = 20.000000 Tolerance = +2.000000/-2.000000 PLATED MILS Quantity = 360
;T02 Holesize 2. = 24.000000 Tolerance = +2.000000/-2.000000 PLATED MILS Quantity = 712
;T03 Holesize 3. = 126.000000 Tolerance = +3.940000/-3.940000 PLATED MILS Quantity = 10
;T04 Holesize 4. = 79.000000 Tolerance = +3.000000/-3.000000 NON_PLATED MILS Quantity = 1
;T05 Holesize 5. = 118.000000 Tolerance = +0.000000/-0.000000 NON_PLATED MILS Quantity = 3
%
G90
T01
X-0017100Y0160000
X-0017000Y0180000
Y0200000
Y0220000...
```

I actually need to take out the size of the hole and the quantity. I used in a row this function to take the size out `=IF(A18="";"";RIGHT((LEFT(A18;26));7))`.
For the quantity I don't know how to do it.

Once I have my hole's size and the quantity, I would like to report them on a table.

What function or macro should I writte please ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you need to save the Excel file as `*.xlsm` not `*.xlsx` to save it including macros.

Comment: You can use replace to remove " Quantity", remembering to take out one of the spaces around it (not both).  Make it do that to a selection, such that columns(3) is the target (if column 3 holds the text).

Comment: Cyril,
Can you please help me for the code because I don't understand very much about VBA... I found the code of importing file in internet.